# SP 2013: Change Page Header/Title

Tags: 2013, script, title

I have a question regarding the title of a Webpart Page: Since the Page Header/Title is also the link of the site, I cannot use some characters (in this case, I would like to have "#" in the title). That does not work, since "#" is not allowed to be in a link.

How can I make this work? What kind of script do I use? I do not have a lot of knowledge regarding scripts etc.

Also, I do not have access to SharePoint Designer.

Any help is appreciated - thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the Title value being displayed using JavaScript. Add a Script Editor Webpart to the webpart page and add this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// wait until the site has loaded
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    // select the page title and update it to "#Example"
    document.querySelector("#DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea a").innerText = "#Example";
});
</script>
```

[Document: DOMContentLoaded event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event)

[HTML DOM Document querySelector()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp)

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! This worked like a charm. One more question: There are some sub-pages where I would like to hide the title. Do you know any way? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Normal subsites? You can then use css instead in a script editor webpart: <style type="text/css">#pageTitle {display:none;}</style>

Comment: Yes! Thanks so much - it worked without any issues! :) Hope you have a great day!

Comment: The same to you! =)